# Make ASP button resemble HTML button

Tags: visual-studio, button, visual-studio-2003

Does anyone know a way to make an asp button...

```
<asp:button runat="server">Button1</asp:button>
```

resemble an HTML input button...

```
<input type="button" value="Button2"/>
```

(or vice versa) in Visual Studio 2003?

Comment: Do you mean, like a hyper link?

Comment: asp:button eventually rendered as HTML button. so your question doesnt make any sense at all.

Comment: How do I make an asp button look exactly the same as an html button. By default they look quite different.

Comment: I see that you're right now adt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to modify your CSS.  Here is something that may help get you going;

```
input.link
{
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #0000ff;
}

a.button
{
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
```

Then update your markup to look something like this;

```
<input type="submit" class="link" value="Submit" />
```

<%= Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "QuoteList", "Quote", new { @class = "button" })%>

This is just off the top of my head so I hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, thank goodness someone understood my witterings :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the runat="server" attribute in your code?

Comment: Yes, I was. Thank you. I'm not any more.

Comment: That's not an answer. It's pointing out a typo in the question, which I've now fixed.